# City/town Lookup functionality for United Kingdom

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, web

Is there any free web service where I can interrogate town or/and city list for United Kingdom? I would like to have a textbox on my mvc3 application where users enter and select their town and/city accurately from the data provided by web service.. I do not really want to keep and maintain list of towns and cities in my database. what is the best way to achieve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `geonames.org`. They got a webservice or a list of geodata you can download.

> The GeoNames geographical database is available for download free of charge under a creative commons attribution license. It contains over 10 million geographical names and consists of 7.5 million unique features whereof 2.8 million populated places and 5.5 million alternate names.

Check out [GeoNames Data](http://www.geonames.org/export/)

#### Update

**olivehour** suggest another free service in a comment, thanks for that!

> Geonames is a great answer. Also, you should check out [Yahoo GeoPlanet](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/). In my experience, it has more up-time than geonames. Also I wrote a WCF lib you can use to consume both geonames and geoplanet in .net: [ngeo.codeplex.com](http://ngeo.codeplex.com). NGeo is available as a NuGet package, just search for NGeo.

Comment: Geonames is a great answer. Also, you should check out Yahoo GeoPlanet. In my experience, it has more up-time than geonames. Also I wrote a WCF lib you can use to consume both geonames and geoplanet in .net: http://ngeo.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks @olivehour, my answer is extended.